# Trouble painting multypolygon with L.vectorGrid.protobuf

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geoserver

Im using L.vectorGrid.protobuf for represent multypolygon but client render draw a line joining the polygons. It shoud be paint only the polygons

I ve already to change styles in vectorgrid options without any success [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue,It was a geoserver conf problem, Geoserver was sending the data like polygon instead Multipolygon